# Apple Mach-O Error

Tags: ios, linker, mach-o

I have Mach-O error in my code.

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIMutableUserNotificationAction", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameThrive(GameThrive.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIMutableUserNotificationCategory", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameThrive(GameThrive.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameThrive(GameThrive.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

What is the probable cause for this?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you trying to build it on?

Comment: Update to Xcode 6.  Those are iOS 8 APIs.